# Render vertices in DX9

Tags: directx, directx-9

If I use a Vertex structure like:

```
struct ColorVertex {
    float x, y, z, rhw;
    DWORD color;    //32bit
};
```

I can draw the primitives after create a vertex buffer for the vertices.

But for a structure without the `rhw`, I have to do the following procedures:

- create a vertex buffer and copy the vertices data
- set the render state by `SetRenderState`
- create a projection matrix
- create a world matrix
- then draw the primitives

Way more complicated. And I just get nothing if ignoring any step up there. So, **is the procedure above is all necessary for the second structure? Any other needed?** I don't see a view port transformation matrix, is it necessary? And no default rendering state is set?

UPDATES:

No, those are not necessary, I can't see the primitives only because I set the z-aix all 0. In D3D, seems like that the projection window is set at z = 1 by default. But I am not sure, plz comments.

Question is for the first structure, my data is :

```
 CUSTOMVERTEX Vertices[] =
    {
        { 150.0f,  50.0f, 0.5f, 1.0f, 0xffff0000, }, // x, y, z, rhw, color
        { 250.0f, 250.0f, 0.5f, 1.0f, 0xff00ff00, },
        {  50.0f, 250.0f, 0.5f, 1.0f, 0xff00ffff, },
    };
```

Still I can see the figure without any transformation and rendering state set.

Comment: Where is the second structure?

Comment: @zdd without a rhw field.

Comment: without the rhw field, how do you know the vertex position?